# how can i view the month date year only? i'm using datetime, data type

Tags: c#, datetime

```
public static void AddEmployee(string EID, string FName, string LName,
int Salary, DateTime Birthday)



buz.AddEmployee(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text,
int.Parse(TextBox4.Text), DateTime.Parse(TextBox6.Text));
```

by this code, i can generate month date year.

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             TextBox6.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
             Calendar1.Visible = true;
         }
```

but when i view it it still includes the time.
how can i view the month date year only?

Comment: Well, `DateTime` will always have a time component. After all, it's basically just an `Int64` value counting Ticks since [01.01.0001 00:00:00.0000000 UTC (gregorian)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx). It's generally accepted that for any usage, where you don't want or need, to just set the time component to all zeros. Most easily done for example like: `dateTimeValue = dateTimeValue.Date;`. So if you want to use `DateTime` (and its many benefits), you have to live with that. Another way would be to store `year`, `month` and `day` values seperatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int year = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year;
int month = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Month;
```